# How to send and receive a Java Object from Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs

How do I send and receive a Java Object from SQS? For instance, I have a java object Log. I send the object to the message queue as

```
this.getSqs().sendMessage(new SendMessageRequest(myQueueUrl, log.toString());
```

However, at the time of retrieving the message from queue, I want to be able to retrieve it as `List<Log>` and use it as a java Log object inside my application. Any pointers on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to serialize the message to a string, additionally making sure that all the characters are in the allowed character range.

One way to do it is to use Java serialization (though it's not the best method for serialization, it often works), and then encode the result using e.g. Base64.

For an example see: [SoftwareMill common Queue](https://github.com/softwaremill/softwaremill-common/blob/master/softwaremill-sqs/src/main/java/com/softwaremill/common/sqs/Queue.java#L55) and [SoftwareMill common Util](https://github.com/softwaremill/softwaremill-common/blob/master/softwaremill-sqs/src/main/java/com/softwaremill/common/sqs/Util.java#L21)

Answer (score 3):

Id use Gson to serialize and deserialize pojo's to strings

you would send the message above as

```
sendMessage(new SendMessageRequest(myQueueUrl,log.toString());

then when you get a List<Messages> messages = sns.read();
for(Message m:messages){
    String json= m.getBody();
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Log l = g.fromJson(json,Log.class);
}
```